# How to pass hostname and securitykey using PHP from website to website to validate

Tags: php, api

Can anyone share you perspective to validate the security key and hostname or IP address.

In Windows XAMPP server else with Cpanel trying out.

Here is the sample one code it is showing for an Wordpress where I'm trying core PHP.

```
define( 'AUTH_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',       'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
```

My expectation to validate the security key and hostname with this it has enter into another website.

Comment: You will have to clarify what you are trying to do, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Agreed, I don't get it either. Please explain in more detail